# How do I create a link to the current database because I am doing a partial deployment?

Tags: hyperlink

Ok this is what I am envisioning but not sure if it can be done...I would appreciate your input.  I am working to create a sharepoint site that has several "sub-pages"  I have almost completed the main pages and was thinking that maybe I could deploy the site and when the user clicks on the "sub-pages" it would automatically take the user to the old database page that corresponds. Then when I am ready to deploy them I could turn off the route to the old database. There has got to be a way to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to create a secondary web application where you attach the old database. Then you point the links of these "sub-pages" pointing to the pages that are in the secondary web application.

More advanced solution would be to create HTTP Handler that intercepts every request and determines whether it is such that needs to be redirected to this secondary web application.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer!  I will look in to the HTTP Handler.